# Cannot run any web application in VS 2010/2012 getting "Unable to start program"

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

Since this morning I cannot run any web application in Visual Studio 2010 or 2012, getting the following error:

[image: VS 2010 error when I try run any web site application]

No break points are being hit in the Global.asax. I thought there's some issue with dll's I'm referencing so I tried creating a clean new web forms and MVC-4 applications using both 2010 & 2012 but still getting the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there's a problem with Internet Explorer(I'm using version 10) If i run the site in Chrome or Firefox it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Try going to `http://localhost:2980` in your browser without debugging in Visual Studio.  It should give you a more accurate error.

Some other things to try

- delete your bin and obj folders (Clean your solution)
- restart Visual Studio or even your OS
- restart IIS
- run `aspnet_regiis -i`

some more things to try

- if you installed web express first, http://forums.asp.net/post/5373941.aspx
- try running visual studio in repair mode

Comment: Thanks for the answer, tried all of the above but still the same issue

Comment: added two more suggestions

Comment: when you loaded it in the browser did you get any more detail on the error?  like what file it was looking for?